# Fetching Objects from Array by passing key & value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

This is my Array of objects. I want to filter the objects by passing query in a function.

```js
const products = [{
    name: "A",
    color: "Blue",
    size: 50
  },
  {
    name: "B",
    color: "Blue",
    size: 60
  },
  {
    name: "C",
    color: "Black",
    size: 70
  },
  {
    name: "D",
    color: "Green",
    size: 50
  }
];
```

My desired output which will filter from the query which I am passing in function which can be anything

```js
{
  name: "A",
  color: "Blue",
  size: 50
}, {
  name: "C",
  color: "Black",
  size: 70
}
```

This is my query object which I will pass to function

```js
const filter = {
  color: ["Blue", "Black"],
  size: [70, 50]
};
```

This is my function which I can assign to other variable and use it for further operations

```
const filteredData = filterIt(products, filter);
```

Comment: that is what issue I have. 
/ /Function
const filterIt = (data, filter) => {
  //console.log(filter);

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    //console.log("through array",data[i][Object.keys(filter)[i]]);
    console.log("through query");

    /* 
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(filter)) {
     // console.log(key, value);
        console.log(data[i])

    } */
  }
};

Comment: Best to add that to the question where it can be properly formatted rather than a comment where it is very hard to read

Comment: ok.. Actually I was not sure about my approach as I am newbie in javascript thats why didnt posted

Comment: What if some value has a `Blue` color, but size different from `70` and `50`? Should it be included or not?

Comment: ya...sorry for last comment m looking for the code which includes the different size objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another option:

```
function filterIt(products, filter) {
  return products.filter(p => {
    for (const k in filter) {
      if (filter[k].indexOf(p[k]) === -1) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  })
}
```

See a [**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/fetching-objects-from-array-by-passing-key-value-in-javascript)

If you want to make an OR instead of an AND in the logic the previous function modified would be:

```
function filterIt(products, filter) {
  return products.filter(p => {
    for (const k in filter) {
      // if a value of any property of the product is contained in a filter array, include it
      if (filter[k].indexOf(p[k]) !== -1) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  })
}
```

See a [**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/fetching-objects-from-array-by-passing-key-value-in-js-or) for this one too :)

Comment: Thank you for your help but I would like to know one thing which you already asked. like if i want to include the values which has blue color but size different. while passing the same query

Comment: @jeetdeveloper See my answer updated, including another demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/fetching-objects-from-array-by-passing-key-value-in-js-or . Notice, that this is an OR among all the filters, not just the `color` or `size`. Let me know if you have any doubts ;)

Comment: If you want to make a more complex comparison and yet keep the function generic, you could need to make the `filter` object more complex and include in it what kind of comparison you want to perform and stuff like that. Otherwise if you want to stick only to `size` you can directly check for the `size` property directly and if it is present then just keep that product in the final result no matter the color matches or not.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the entries of the filter object and take key and value for checking with `includes`.

```js
const
    filterBy = filter => o => Object.entries(filter).every(([k, v]) => v.includes(o[k])),
    filterIt = (array, filter) => array.filter(filterBy(filter)),
    products = [{ name: "A", color: "Blue", size: 50 }, { name: "B", color: "Blue", size: 60 }, { name: "C", color: "Black", size: 70 }, { name: "D", color: "Green", size: 50 }],
    filter = { color: ["Blue", "Black"], size: [70, 50] },
    filteredData = filterIt(products, filter);

 console.log(filteredData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const products = [{
    name: "A",
    color: "Blue",
    size: 50
  },
  {
    name: "B",
    color: "Blue",
    size: 60
  },
  {
    name: "C",
    color: "Black",
    size: 70
  },
  {
    name: "D",
    color: "Green",
    size: 50
  }
];
const filter = {
  color: ["Blue", "Black"],
  size: [70, 50]
};


let filterIt = (products, filter) => {

  return products.filter(p => {
    
    //get all filter keys
    let keys = Object.keys(filter);
    
    let validkeys = [];
    
    keys.forEach(k=>{
      // check if filter property exist and includes filter value
      if(p.hasOwnProperty(k) && filter[k].includes(p[k])){
        validkeys.push(true);
      }
      
    })
    
    //check all filter matches
    return validkeys.length === keys.length;
    
  });

}

const filteredData = filterIt(products, filter);
console.log("...filteredData", filteredData);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I would like to know one thing which you already asked. like if i want to include the values which has blue color but size different. while passing the same query

Comment: @jeetdeveloper then push valid filter keys  validkeys.push(k);  Then valid product can be determined like   return validkeys.includes('color'). It is all about manipulating filter condition.